# Como interpolar elementos de uma matriz no python?

Tags: python

Boa tarde Pessoal!
Sou novo no python e estou tentado interpolar valores entre duas colunas de uma matriz retangular.
Inicialmente criei uma matriz de zeros `(nx=383 nz=125)`. Depois preenchi a matriz nas posições `nx=5` e `nx=380`. Gostaria de preencher as posições entre estes dois pontos com uma interpolção dos valores nestes dois pontos. Estou tentado as interpolções `1d` e `2d` mas ambas reclamam das dimensões não serem as mesmas. Alguém pode me ajudar?
Grato

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.interpolate import griddata


# In[2]:


nx = 383
nz = 125


# In[7]:


perfilf=model[380, 0:125] 
plt.plot( perfilf )
plt.title("perfilf")
plt.show()


# In[8]:


perfili=model[5, 0:125] 
plt.plot( perfili )
plt.title("perfili")
plt.show()


# In[9]:


m0=np.zeros((nx,nz))
m0[5,:] = perfili
m0[380,:]=perfilf
plt.imshow(m0.T, aspect='auto')
plt.title("teste")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```